# Ubuntu 14.04 installation for Surface Pro 3

Tags: system-installation

i booted into usb ubuntu 14.04 (Gnome Ubuntu), and installed on the partition on the SSD, but now grub does not work and i do not see the option to boot into ubuntu. its directly goes into win 8.1. Need help to fix this ?

Thanks
B

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the Ubuntu USB to boot into an Ubuntu Live Session, then use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
sudo boot-repair
```